# How to use Reactive Extensions to cache, throttle, and relay multiple events?

Tags: c#, events, caching, system.reactive, reactive-extensions-js

I am trying to learn the new Reactive Extensions framework for .Net, and it sounds like the perfect solution for my application.  After studying examples ( and being fairly weak with LINQ still ), I am struggling to figure out how to leverage the RX framework to accomplish the task below.

The goal is to create a configurable event "relay" between a custom data source and the GUI.  The relay will use LINQ to test and filter the incoming events, cache the qualified events in a list while waiting for the next time interval, then sync to the GUI thread and playback the events in the order that they were received.

How can you use RX to coordinate caching, filtering, and relaying multiple events, such as events for adding, changing, and removing values from a custom data source ?

This may be asking a lot, but any guidance in how to approach this problem would be very appreciated.  See example code below...

```
public delegate void EventDelegateAdd(Thing thing);
public delegate void EventDelegateChange(Thing thing);
public delegate void EventDelegateRemove(Thing thing);

public delegate void EventDelegateBulkChangesStart();
public delegate void EventDelegateBulkChangesEnd();

// The "Things" that are stored in MyCustomDataSource

public class Thing
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public object OtherStuff { get; set; }
}

// A custom observable data source with events that indicate when Things are
// added, changed, or removed.

public class MyCustomDataSource
{
    public event EventDelegateAdd AddingThing;
    public event EventDelegateChange ChangingThing;
    public event EventDelegateRemove RemovingThing;

    // The rest of the class that manages the database of Things...
}

// This class forms a configurable event bridge between the MyCustomDataSource and
// the GUI.  The goal is to cache, filter, and throttle the events so that the GUI
// updates only occasionally with bulk changes that are relevant for that control.

public class MyEventCachingBridge
{
    private MyCustomDataSource mSource;

    public event EventDelegateAdd AddingThing;
    public event EventDelegateChange ChangingThing;
    public event EventDelegateRemove RemovingThing;

    public event EventDelegateBulkChangesStart BulkChangesStart;
    public event EventDelegateBulkChangesEnd BulkChangesEnd;


    public MyEventCachingBridge(MyCustomDataSource source, int eventRelayInterval)
    {
        mSource = source;

        // Magical Reactive Extensions code goes here that subscribes to all 3 events...
        //
        //   mSource.AddingThing
        //   mSource.ChangingThing
        //   mSource.RemovingThing
        // 
        //  ...filters and records a list of the events as they are received ( maintaining order of events too ),
        //  then every eventRelayInterval milliseconds, plays back the events in bulk to update the GUI 
        //  ( on the GUIs thread ).  Note that LINQ will be used to filter the Things so that a subset of
        //  Thing changes are relayed to the GUI - i.e. - not all Thing events are observed by the GUI.

    }


    public void PlayBackCachedEvents()
    {
        BulkChangesStart();   // Raise Event to notify GUI to suspend screen updates

        // Play back the list of events to push changes to ListView, TreeView, graphs, etc...
        //
        //  this.AddingThing(Thing);        // Fire events in order received
        //  this.ChangingThing(Thing);      // Fire events in order received
        //  this.RemovingThing(Thing);      // Fire events in order received

        BulkChangesEnd();   // Raise Event to notify GUI to allow control refresh
    }
```

Given the task described, I am not sure what should be coordinated in general class code, and what should be buried in RX statements.

I also appreciate the fact that combining the 3 events into a single event with an enumeration indicating the purpose of the event would greatly simplify things, however there are a lot more than just 3 events to cache in the actual application.  I don't want the overhead of having to use constant Switch statement testing to identify each event.  There will be large volumes of events routed to potentially numerous GUI interfaces.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, I love playing with Rx...here's one approach; first by part, then the whole thing:

EDIT: modified to suit comments

First, you'll need to set up the streams for the events - While we're at it, let's replace the "old" .NET event pattern the bridge exposes with the "new hawtness" of Rx:

```
public Subject<Thing> BufferedAdds {get; private set;}
public Subject<Thing> BufferedChanges {get; private set;}
public Subject<Thing> BufferedRemoves {get; private set;}

_adds = Observable.FromEvent<EventDelegateAdd, Thing>(
    ev => new EventDelegateAdd(ev),
    h => mSource.AddingThing += h,
    h => mSource.AddingThing -= h);
BufferedAdds = new Subject<Thing>();

_changes = Observable.FromEvent<EventDelegateChange, Thing>(
    ev => new EventDelegateChange(ev),
    h => mSource.ChangingThing += h,
    h => mSource.ChangingThing -= h);
BufferedChanges = new Subject<Thing>();

_removes = Observable.FromEvent<EventDelegateRemove, Thing>(
    ev => new EventDelegateRemove(ev),
    h => mSource.RemovingThing += h,
    h => mSource.RemovingThing -= h);
BufferedRemoves = new Subject<Thing>();
```

We're also going to tie everything to an `IScheduler` now - `IScheduler` usage is a key facet for testing this bloody stuff without `Thread.Sleep`'ing all over the place - I highly recommend researching this topic!

```
public MyEventCachingBridge(
    MyCustomDataSource source, 
    int eventRelayInterval, 
    IScheduler scheduler)
{
```

Then you'll want to combine all the incoming events into a single stream, then "chunk" that stream based on a time window - the `Buffer` operator is ideal for this:

```
_buffer = Observable.Merge(scheduler,
        _adds.Select(e => Tuple.Create(e, ThingEventType.Add)), 
        _changes.Select(e => Tuple.Create(e, ThingEventType.Change)), 
        _removes.Select(e => Tuple.Create(e, ThingEventType.Remove)))
    .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(eventRelayInterval), scheduler);
```

Notice I'm packing the type of the event back into the stream - this is so we can take the appropriate action during the playback - the enum is:

```
private enum ThingEventType
{
    Add,
    Change,
    Remove
}
```

So now we'll need something to listen to and hold the batched events - there are a number of options here, but let's use a simple `List` with synchronization:

```
private Queue<IList<Tuple<Thing,ThingEventType>>> _eventQueue;
private static object SyncRoot = new object();

_eventQueue = new Queue<IList<Tuple<Thing,ThingEventType>>>();

// A serial disposable is a sort of "Disposable holder" - when you change it's
// Disposable member, it auto-disposes what you originally had there...no real
// need for it here, but potentially useful later
_watcherDisposable = new SerialDisposable();
_watcherDisposable.Disposable = _buffer
    .ObserveOn(_scheduler)
    .Subscribe(batch => 
    { 
        lock(SyncRoot) { _eventQueue.Enqueue(batch); }
    });
    _disposables.Add(_watcherDisposable);
```

Let's also "auto-wire" the Playback burst to pulse every `eventRelayInterval` ms:

```
var pulse = Observable.Interval(
       TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(eventRelayInterval), 
       _scheduler);
_disposables.Add(pulse
      .ObserveOn(_scheduler)
      .Subscribe(x => PlayBackCachedEvents()));
```

Subscriptions are always IDisposable, and you *will* want to dispose them, so let's add in some stuff for that:

```
public class MyEventCachingBridge : IDisposable
{
    CompositeDisposable _disposables;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _disposables.Dispose();
    }
```

And now for the playback:

```
public void PlayBackCachedEvents()
{
    BulkChangesStart();   // Raise Event to notify GUI to suspend screen updates

    // Play back the list of events to push changes 
    lock(SyncRoot)
    {
        foreach(var batch in _eventQueue)
        {
            // Play back the list of events to push changes to ListView, TreeView, graphs, etc...            
            foreach(var evt in batch)
            {
                switch(evt.Item2)
                {
                    case ThingEventType.Add: BufferedAdds.OnNext(evt.Item1); break;
                    case ThingEventType.Change: BufferedChanges.OnNext(evt.Item1);break;
                    case ThingEventType.Remove: BufferedRemoves.OnNext(evt.Item1);break;
                }
            }
        }
        _eventQueue.Clear();
    }
    BulkChangesEnd();   // Raise Event to notify GUI to allow control refresh
}
```

NOW - we want to be all fancy on the consumer side as well, so let's mock up a UI window (this is WPF, adjust accordingly):

```
public class BridgeConsumer : Window, IDisposable
{
    private readonly CompositeDisposable _disposables;
    private IScheduler _scheduler;
    private StackPanel _panel;

    public void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs ea)
    {
        _panel = new StackPanel();
        this.Content = _panel;
    }

    public BridgeConsumer(MyEventCachingBridge bridge, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        // for cleanup of any subscriptions
        _disposables = new CompositeDisposable();
        _disposables.Add(bridge);
        _scheduler = scheduler;

        Loaded += OnLoaded;

        // setup a listener for the bulk start/end events on the bridge
        var bulkStart = Observable.FromEvent(
                h => bridge.BulkChangesStart += new EventDelegateBulkChangesStart(h),
                h => bridge.BulkChangesStart -= new EventDelegateBulkChangesStart(h));
        var bulkEnd = Observable.FromEvent(
                h => bridge.BulkChangesEnd += new EventDelegateBulkChangesEnd(h),
                h => bridge.BulkChangesEnd -= new EventDelegateBulkChangesEnd(h));

        // the "meaty bit" - 
        //    1. create a "window" defined by bulk start/end events
        //    2. inside that "window", trap any occurrences on a 
        //          merged view of adds/changes/removes
        //    3. foreach event in that window, select that event
        //         (i.e., give us window contents as a stream of sorts)
        var bridgeWatcher =
            from thingEventWindow in 
                Observable.Merge(
                    bridge.BufferedAdds.Select(t => Tuple.Create("add", t)), 
                    bridge.BufferedChanges.Select(t => Tuple.Create("change", t)), 
                    bridge.BufferedRemoves.Select(t => Tuple.Create("remove", t))
                )
                .Window(bulkStart, start => bulkEnd)
            from thingEvent in thingEventWindow
            select thingEvent;

        // this could just as easily be a method, a bound call to the viewmodel, etc
        Action<Thing, string, DateTimeOffset> addToList = (thing, msg, ts) => 
        {
            var text = new TextBlock() 
            { 
                Text = string.Format(
                    "At:{0} Key:{2} Msg:{3} - nowTime = {1}", 
                    thing.TimeStamp, 
                    ts, 
                    thing.Key, 
                    msg) };
            _panel.Children.Add(text);
        };

        _disposables.Add(bridgeWatcher
            // CAREFUL! "ObserveOn" means what you'd think "SubscribeOn" would
            .ObserveOnDispatcher()
            .Subscribe(tup => 
            {
                addToList(tup.Item2, tup.Item1, _scheduler.Now);
            }));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // clean up
        if(_disposables != null) _disposables.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The whole shebang:

```
void Main()
{
    var scheduler = Scheduler.Default;
    var rnd = new Random();
    var canceller = new CancellationTokenSource();

    var source = new MyCustomDataSource();    
    var eventRelayInterval = 2000;
    var bridge = new MyEventCachingBridge(source, eventRelayInterval, scheduler);

    var window = new BridgeConsumer(bridge);
    window.Closed += (o,e) => { canceller.Cancel(); window.Dispose(); };
    window.Show();

    Task.Factory.StartNew(
        () => 
        {
            while(true)
            {
                var thing = new Thing() 
                { 
                    Key = "added thing " + rnd.Next(0, 100), 
                    Title = "title for added thing", 
                    TimeStamp = scheduler.Now.DateTime 
                };
                source.FireAdd(thing);
                Thread.Sleep(rnd.Next(1,10) * 100);
            }
        }, canceller.Token);            
}

public class BridgeConsumer : Window, IDisposable
{
    private readonly CompositeDisposable _disposables;
    private StackPanel _panel;

    public void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs ea)
    {
        _panel = new StackPanel();
        this.Content = _panel;
    }

    public BridgeConsumer(MyEventCachingBridge bridge)
    {
        _disposables = new CompositeDisposable();
        _disposables.Add(bridge);

        Loaded += OnLoaded;

        var bulkStart = Observable.FromEvent(
                h => bridge.BulkChangesStart += new EventDelegateBulkChangesStart(h),
                h => bridge.BulkChangesStart -= new EventDelegateBulkChangesStart(h));
        var bulkEnd = Observable.FromEvent(
                h => bridge.BulkChangesEnd += new EventDelegateBulkChangesEnd(h),
                h => bridge.BulkChangesEnd -= new EventDelegateBulkChangesEnd(h));
        var bridgeWatcher =
            from thingEventWindow in 
                Observable.Merge(
                    bridge.BufferedAdds.Select(t => Tuple.Create("add", t)), 
                    bridge.BufferedChanges.Select(t => Tuple.Create("change", t)), 
                    bridge.BufferedRemoves.Select(t => Tuple.Create("remove", t))
                )
                .Window(bulkStart, start => bulkEnd)
            from thingEvent in thingEventWindow
            select thingEvent;

        Action<Thing, string> addToList = (thing, msg) => 
        {
            var text = new TextBlock() 
            { 
                Text = string.Format(
                    "At:{0} Key:{1} Msg:{2}", 
                    thing.TimeStamp, 
                    thing.Key, 
                    msg) 
            };
            _panel.Children.Add(text);
        };

        _disposables.Add(bridgeWatcher.ObserveOnDispatcher().Subscribe(tup => 
            {
                addToList(tup.Item2, tup.Item1);
            }));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if(_disposables != null) _disposables.Dispose();
    }
}


public delegate void EventDelegateAdd(Thing thing);
public delegate void EventDelegateChange(Thing thing);
public delegate void EventDelegateRemove(Thing thing);

public delegate void EventDelegateBulkChangesStart();
public delegate void EventDelegateBulkChangesEnd();

// The "Things" that are stored in MyCustomDataSource

public class Thing
{
    public DateTime TimeStamp {get; set;}
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public object OtherStuff { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("At:{0} Key:{1} Title:{2}", this.TimeStamp, this.Key, this.Title);        
    }
}

// A custom observable data source with events that indicate when Things are
// added, changed, or removed.

public class MyCustomDataSource
{
    public event EventDelegateAdd AddingThing = delegate { };
    public event EventDelegateChange ChangingThing = delegate { };
    public event EventDelegateRemove RemovingThing = delegate { };

    // The rest of the class that manages the database of Things...
    public void FireAdd(Thing toAdd)
    {
        AddingThing(toAdd);
    }
    public void FireChange(Thing toChange)
    {
        ChangingThing(toChange);
    }
    public void FireRemove(Thing toRemove)
    {
        RemovingThing(toRemove);
    }
}

// This class forms a configurable event bridge between the MyCustomDataSource and
// the GUI.  The goal is to cache, filter, and throttle the events so that the GUI
// updates only occasionally with bulk changes that are relevant for that control.

public class MyEventCachingBridge : IDisposable
{
    private enum ThingEventType
    {
        Add,
        Change,
        Remove
    }

    private MyCustomDataSource mSource;
    private IScheduler _scheduler;

    public event EventDelegateBulkChangesStart BulkChangesStart = delegate { };
    public event EventDelegateBulkChangesEnd BulkChangesEnd = delegate { };

    public IObservable<Thing> RawAdds {get; private set;}
    public IObservable<Thing> RawChanges {get; private set;}
    public IObservable<Thing> RawRemoves {get; private set;}

    public Subject<Thing> BufferedAdds {get; private set;}
    public Subject<Thing> BufferedChanges {get; private set;}
    public Subject<Thing> BufferedRemoves {get; private set;}

    private readonly IObservable<IList<Tuple<Thing,ThingEventType>>> _buffer;
    private List<IList<Tuple<Thing,ThingEventType>>> _eventQueue;
    private static object SyncRoot = new object();

    private readonly CompositeDisposable _disposables;
    private readonly SerialDisposable _watcherDisposable;

    public MyEventCachingBridge(MyCustomDataSource source, int eventRelayInterval, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        _disposables = new CompositeDisposable();
        mSource = source;
        _scheduler = scheduler;
        _eventQueue = new List<IList<Tuple<Thing,ThingEventType>>>();

        // Magical Reactive Extensions code goes here that subscribes to all 3 events...
        //
        //   mSource.AddingThing
        //   mSource.ChangingThing
        //   mSource.RemovingThing
        // 
        //  ...filters and records a list of the events as they are received ( maintaining order of events too ),
        //  then every eventRelayInterval milliseconds, plays back the events in bulk to update the GUI 
        //  ( on the GUIs thread ).  Note that LINQ will be used to filter the Things so that a subset of
        //  Thing changes are relayed to the GUI - i.e. - not all Thing events are observed by the GUI.
        RawAdds = Observable.FromEvent<EventDelegateAdd, Thing>(
            ev => new EventDelegateAdd(ev),
            h => mSource.AddingThing += h,
            h => mSource.AddingThing -= h);
        BufferedAdds = new Subject<Thing>();

        RawChanges = Observable.FromEvent<EventDelegateChange, Thing>(
            ev => new EventDelegateChange(ev),
            h => mSource.ChangingThing += h,
            h => mSource.ChangingThing -= h);
        BufferedChanges = new Subject<Thing>();

        RawRemoves = Observable.FromEvent<EventDelegateRemove, Thing>(
            ev => new EventDelegateRemove(ev),
            h => mSource.RemovingThing += h,
            h => mSource.RemovingThing -= h);
        BufferedRemoves = new Subject<Thing>();

        _buffer = Observable.Merge(
                    _scheduler,
                    RawAdds.Select(e => Tuple.Create(e, ThingEventType.Add)), 
                    RawChanges.Select(e => Tuple.Create(e, ThingEventType.Change)), 
                    RawRemoves.Select(e => Tuple.Create(e, ThingEventType.Remove)))
            .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(eventRelayInterval), _scheduler);

        _watcherDisposable = new SerialDisposable();
        _watcherDisposable.Disposable = _buffer
            .ObserveOn(_scheduler)
            .Subscribe(batch => 
            { 
                lock(SyncRoot) { _eventQueue.Add(batch); }
            });
        _disposables.Add(_watcherDisposable);

        var pulse = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(eventRelayInterval), _scheduler);
        _disposables.Add(pulse.ObserveOn(_scheduler).Subscribe(x => PlayBackCachedEvents()));
    }

    private void PlayBackCachedEvents()
    {
        BulkChangesStart();   // Raise Event to notify GUI to suspend screen updates

        try
        {            
            //_eventQueue.Dump();
            lock(SyncRoot)
            {
                foreach(var batch in _eventQueue)
                {
                    // Play back the list of events to push changes to ListView, TreeView, graphs, etc...            
                    foreach(var evt in batch)
                    {
                        switch(evt.Item2)
                        {
                            case ThingEventType.Add: BufferedAdds.OnNext(evt.Item1); break;
                            case ThingEventType.Change: BufferedChanges.OnNext(evt.Item1);break;
                            case ThingEventType.Remove: BufferedRemoves.OnNext(evt.Item1);break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                _eventQueue.Clear();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception during playback:" + ex);
        }
        BulkChangesEnd();   // Raise Event to notify GUI to allow control refresh
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _disposables.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks awesome, thanks !!!   I will integrate it, try it, and report back....

Comment: One detail is missing - syncing to the GUI thread.  Any suggestions on how to properly make use of ObserveOn to switch threads before playing back the cached events ?  Thanks.

Comment: OK, I see where the disconnect is.  I wasn't clearly describing how the playback mechanism was intended to work.  The PlayBackChachedEvents should be called automatically by the RX framework after syncing to the GUI thread every interval if there are events pending in the queue.  The result is that the GUI can hook the events from the bridge and safely push data to the controls directly.  The event bridge is receiving random events from the data source, caching them, then bursting the cache to the GUI every interval with framing events to define the start and stop of bulk changes.

Comment: So that logic would be in the "consumer" of the bridge - something in the ui, in your case. You'd use a mechanism similar to the way I bind to the.net event streams to do this, creating another IObservable, which you would then SubscribeOn to get the correct thread. When I get a chance I'll see about adding an example.

Comment: Beautiful !!  Thanks so much for all of your help JerKimball !!

Answer (score 2):

I am a bit late to this particular show but I think what you need is an observable cache / list which will give a change set of all adds, updates and removes.

I have implemented this and made it open source:

Blog: http://dynamicdataproject.wordpress.com/

Demo: https://github.com/RolandPheasant/TradingDemo